# How to upload image on elgg using rest url?

Tags: api, url, rest, restful-authentication, elgg

I am trying to athenticate from the **elgg** local server.
by refering 
http://www.danielansari.com/wordpress/2008/12/how-to-use-the-rest-api-in-elgg-11/

I am getting following error:

```
Status: **** ERROR (-1) ****  
Message: Method call 'login' has not been implemented. 
Result: exception 'APIException' with message 'Method call 'login' has not been implemented.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\elgg1.6.1\engine\lib\api.php:562
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\elgg1.6.1\services\api\rest.php(46): execute_method()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\elgg1.6.1\engine\lib\api.php(1219): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\elgg1.6.1\engine\lib\pagehandler.php(42): api_endpoint_handler('login', Array, '')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\elgg1.6.1\engine\handlers\pagehandler.php(23): page_handler(Array, 'api')
#4 {main}
```

Basically my aim is to upload an image in a community made by using ELGG. But In this place only I am stuck.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't help you with that exception, but I can tell you that there is no way directly in Elgg's REST API to upload an image. I tried doing this and had to replicate the logic of the upload.php action in my own huge honking function.